# Authentication via LDAP: where is ldap_search_ext defined?

Tags: ssh, rhel, authentication, ldap, sssd

There are two RHEL 8 servers which have been provisioned from the same template, with some manual fix and tweaking done manually on the first server only. They allow SSH user authentication via a remote LDAP server, and have been configured with authselect:

```
authselect select sssd --force
```

The first server works perfectly, while on the second one the SSH authentication fails. I'm looking to find the difference between them, because their LDAP, PAM, `sssd`, and `nscd` configs appear the same.

EDIT 11/6: The `nslcd` daemon is inactive; it has the default config, identical on both servers.
It is also worth noting that `getent passwd` correctly returns all LDAP users, but these users cannot login via SSH. The `sshd` config is the same, too.

By reading the `sssd` logs, I found out that the first server calls (correctly) `ldap_search_ext` with

```
[(&(uid=dr01)(objectclass=posixAccount)(&(uidNumber=*)(!(uidNumber=0))))][dc=mydomain,dc=org]
```

while the second one uses (failing) the search

```
[(&(uid=dr01)(objectclass=posixAccount)(uid=*)(&(uidNumber=*)(!(uidNumber=0))))][dc=mydomain,dc=org]
```

So, on the second server the query includes an additional `(uid=*)`. It also refers to BE_REQ_USER vs BE_REQ_INITGROUPS in the first search (see logs below). This returns zero results.

So, I'd like to know where the call to `ldap_search_ext` is defined.

Here is an excerpt of the logs from the first server:

```
(Fri Jun  7 15:15:46 2019) [sssd[be[mydomain.org]]] [dp_get_account_info_send] (0x0200): Got request for [0x3][BE_REQ_INITGROUPS][name=dr01@mydomain.org]
(Fri Jun  7 15:15:46 2019) [sssd[be[mydomain.org]]] [sss_domain_get_state] (0x1000): Domain mydomain.org is Active
(Fri Jun  7 15:15:46 2019) [sssd[be[mydomain.org]]] [dp_attach_req] (0x0400): DP Request [Initgroups #13]: New request. Flags [0x0001].
(Fri Jun  7 15:15:46 2019) [sssd[be[mydomain.org]]] [dp_attach_req] (0x0400): Number of active DP request: 1
(Fri Jun  7 15:15:46 2019) [sssd[be[mydomain.org]]] [sss_domain_get_state] (0x1000): Domain mydomain.org is Active
(Fri Jun  7 15:15:46 2019) [sssd[be[mydomain.org]]] [sdap_get_initgr_next_base] (0x0400): Searching for users with base [dc=mydomain,dc=org]
(Fri Jun  7 15:15:46 2019) [sssd[be[mydomain.org]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x0400): calling ldap_search_ext with [(&(uid=dr01)(objectclass=posixAccount)(&(uidNumber=*)(!(uidNumber=0))))][dc=mydomain,dc=org].
(Fri Jun  7 15:15:46 2019) [sssd[be[mydomain.org]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [objectClass]
(Fri Jun  7 15:15:46 2019) [sssd[be[mydomain.org]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [uid]
(Fri Jun  7 15:15:46 2019) [sssd[be[mydomain.org]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [userPassword]
(Fri Jun  7 15:15:46 2019) [sssd[be[mydomain.org]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [uidNumber]
(Fri Jun  7 15:15:46 2019) [sssd[be[mydomain.org]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [gidNumber]
(...)
(Fri Jun  7 15:20:50 2019) [sssd[be[mydomain.org]]] [sdap_search_user_process] (0x0400): Search for users, returned 1 results.
```

and the second one:

```
(Fri Jun  7 15:20:50 2019) [sssd[be[mydomain.org]]] [dp_get_account_info_send] (0x0200): Got request for [0x1][BE_REQ_USER][name=dr01@mydomain.org]
(Fri Jun  7 15:20:50 2019) [sssd[be[mydomain.org]]] [dp_attach_req] (0x0400): DP Request [Account #8]: New request. Flags [0x0001].
(Fri Jun  7 15:20:50 2019) [sssd[be[mydomain.org]]] [dp_attach_req] (0x0400): Number of active DP request: 1
(Fri Jun  7 15:20:50 2019) [sssd[be[mydomain.org]]] [sss_domain_get_state] (0x1000): Domain mydomain.org is Active
(Fri Jun  7 15:20:50 2019) [sssd[be[mydomain.org]]] [sdap_search_user_next_base] (0x0400): Searching for users with base [dc=mydomain,dc=org]
(Fri Jun  7 15:20:50 2019) [sssd[be[mydomain.org]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x0400): calling ldap_search_ext with [(&(uid=dr01)(objectclass=posixAccount)(uid=*)(&(uidNumber=*)(!(uidNumber=0))))][dc=mydomain,dc=org].
(Fri Jun  7 15:20:50 2019) [sssd[be[mydomain.org]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [objectClass]
(Fri Jun  7 15:20:50 2019) [sssd[be[mydomain.org]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [uid]
(Fri Jun  7 15:20:50 2019) [sssd[be[mydomain.org]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [userPassword]
(Fri Jun  7 15:20:50 2019) [sssd[be[mydomain.org]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [uidNumber]
(Fri Jun  7 15:20:50 2019) [sssd[be[mydomain.org]]] [sdap_get_generic_ext_step] (0x1000): Requesting attrs: [gidNumber]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the problem.  The `sssd` configuration contains the line

```
ldap_access_filter = (host=<hostname>.mydomain.org)
```

where *hostname* is the local host name for each server. However, the second server wasn't referenced in the LDAP server, only the first one was. Adding an entry for the second server on the LDAP solved the issue.